# Создание TextView во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-textview

Мне нужно создать TextView во фрагменте, но оно не создаётся. Вот код:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(inflater.getContext());
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpView = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView tv = new TextView(inflater.getContext());
tv.setText("РАБОТААААЙ");
tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
linearLayout.addView(tv);
```

Пробовал по другому контекст вызывать, всё равно не получается. Просто белый экран и всё.

Comment: А `linearLayout` Вы на экран добавляете?

Comment: В xml файле стоит linearLayout

Comment: Ну и пусть стоит) Вы тут `LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(inflater.getContext());` себе новый создали и с ним работаете, а на экране его нет))) Найдите свой `LinearLayout` из разметки по `id` и в него `TextView` добавляйте)

Comment: Спасибо, всё  теперь добавляется

Comment: Не забудьте оформить ответ на свой вопрос, спасете кому-нибудь время в будущем и подымете себе карму) Удачи!